# Comparar datas do YouTube e Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, youtube

Através do API do YT, consigo a data do vídeo neste formato (UTC):

```
publishedAt: "2015-09-17T00:01:56.000Z"
```

E no Facebook, inspecionando o código fonte vejo que usam:

```
<abbr title="Quinta, 17 de setembro de 2015 às 06:59" data-utime="1442465986" data-shorten="1" class="timestamp livetimestamp">5 h</abbr>
```

De acordo com [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130985/javascript-date-from-utc-to-local-time):

> utime is UNIX_TIMESTAMP from a datetime (UTC) let's say 1402355007 for the UTC datetime of 2014-06-10 00:03:27

Quero comparar exatamente aqueles dois posts (YT e FB), então se fizer o seguinte para a data do Facebook:

```
var ms = 1442465986 * 1000;
dt = new Date(ms);
console.log(dt)
```

Obtenho:

```
Thu Sep 17 2015 06:59:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Em teoria, quase sete horas depois do YouTube. O CEST é o horário de verão da Europa Central. Minhas dúvidas são

- como converter o `publishedAt` em `utime` e comparar os dois?
- o YouTube [não explica qual GMT usa](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=en#youtube_data_api_tag_published), será que a referência é o +0000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Até onde sei o JS automaticamente faz a conversão. Fiz alguns testes aqui no console do Chrome, segue o código:

```js
var utime  = 1442465986 * 1000,
    ytData = "2015-09-17T00:01:56.000Z";

var d1  = new Date(utime),
    d2  = new Date(ytData),
    dif = parseInt(dayToHours(dateDifference(d1,d2)));

console.log("A diferença entre as datas é de : " + dif + " horas");

function dateDifference(d1, d2) {
  return d1 > d2 ? (d1 - d2) / 86400000 : (d1 - d2) / 86400000;
}

function dayToHours(day) {
  return day * 24;
}
```

Comment: Só aquele `return d1 > d2` que tem que ser ajustado.