# PHP - Converter padrão ISO8601 (usado pelo YouTube) para segundos

Tags: php, data, youtube

Preciso converter **para segundos** um tempo recebido no padrão **ISO8601**, usado pelo YouTube. Alguém conhece alguma função para esta finalidade?

**Exemplificando:**

Se pego pela API do YouTube a duração de um vídeo **PT1M31S**, gostaria de converter tudo isso apenas para **segundos**. Existe uma função nativa do PHP para isso? **Nesse exemplo o resultado seria 91 segundos**.

Comment: O `date` serve para muitas coisas, capaz de ajudar neste caso. Agora, da forma que está a pergunta obriga as pessoas pesquisem o que é o ISO8601, e saibam de que tipo de variável e o formato que você está obtendo a informação, e ainda se arrisquem a dar uma resposta que não é a que você espera. Se você [edit] a pergunta e puser mais detalhes, ajuda todo mundo.

Comment: Não vou votar como duplicata, mas é quase: [Comparar datas do YouTube e Facebook](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87399/201), mas votei na qualidade da pergunta pelas razões expostas pelo Bacco; por favor, melhore a exposição do seu problema.

Comment: Amigo sei que vai entender isto como uma critica construtiva, não poste respostas dentro da pergunta, já tem pontos o suficiente e tem um bom tempo de casa pra saber que aqui somos um Q&A, portanto o correto é formular uma resposta, se a pergunta esta bloqueada, edite apenas a parte da duvida e ela vai entrar na fila de analise pra que outros usuários possam votar pra reabrir, após reaberta poste a resposta. :) Espero que entenda como uma critica boa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu estava esperando sair do estado pendente para inserir como resposta certa. Justamente o que foi removido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo de função PHP para converter o formato de duração do YouTube para segundos:

```
function yt2seconds($youtube_time) {
   preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);

   if (count($parts[0]) == 1) {
      array_unshift($parts[0], "0", "0");
   } elseif (count($parts[0]) == 2) {
      array_unshift($parts[0], "0");
   }

   $sec_init = $parts[0][2];
   $seconds = $sec_init%60;
   $seconds_overflow = floor($sec_init/60);

   $min_init = $parts[0][1] + $seconds_overflow;
   $minutes = ($min_init)%60;
   $minutes_overflow = floor(($min_init)/60);

   $hours = $parts[0][0] + $minutes_overflow;

   $conv = $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;

   sscanf($conv, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
   $time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;

   return $time_seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

PT1M31S é um formato de tempo, significa período de tempo de 1 minuto e 31 segundos, então trate essa string como um DateTime.
 Crie uma data nova e adicione essa intervalo através do método [add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php), que recebe como argumento um [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) que é exatamente a string
 PT1M31S, feito isso basta converter o 01:31 em segundos usando [date_parsed()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

```
$duracao = new DateTime('@0');
$duracao->add(new DateInterval('PT1M31S'));

$parsed = date_parse($duracao->format('H:i:s'));
$segundos = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];

echo $segundos;
```

Ou de forma simplificada, crie um objeto DateInterval para traduzir o período de tempo em horas/minutos/segundos e depois efetue o cálculo para converter esses valores em segundos. Caso utilize esse código em vários lugares sugiro que troque os valores `3600` e `60` por constantes para dar maior semântica, ex: `const SEGUNDOS_EM_UMA_HORA = 3600`

```
$intervalo = new DateInterval('PT1M31S');
$segundos = $intervalo->h * 3600 + $intervalo->i * 60 + $intervalo->s; 
echo $segundos;
```

Baseado em:

[Convert youtube Api v3 video duration in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24393769/1342547)

[How to convert a “HH:MM:SS” string to seconds with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4605117/1342547)

Comment: Só a título de curiosidade, pra que serve esse `'@0'` no Datetime?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe server para especificar um unix timestamp, no caso duração vai iniciar com `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000` e não a data/hora local. Depois da chamada de `add()` vai mudar para: `1970-01-01 00:01:31.000000`